# getting an error when fetching data from database - Undefined property: CI_Loader::$m

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Here am getting error on view page am new to codeigniter please help me...

this one is in view page

```
foreach($this->m->gettable() as $row)

{

    echo "<tr>
    <td>$row->id</td>
    <td>$row->studentname</td>
    <td>$row->gender</td>
    <td>$row->phone</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>";

}
```

In model page

```
function gettable()

    {

        $query=$this->db->get('tblstudent');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

In controller page

```
public function _construct()

{

        parent::_construct();
        //call model
        $this->load->model("StudentModel","m");
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view("index");
    }
    function savedata()
    {
        //create array for get data from index
    $data=array(
                      'studentname' => $this->input->post('studentname'),
                      'gender'  =>  $this->input->post('gender'),
                      'phone'  =>  $this->input->post('phone')
                   );



     //mean that insert into database table name tblstudent

        $this->db->insert('tblstudent',$data);

    //mean that when insert already it will go to page index    
        redirect("Student/index");
    }
```

Comment: what is your model name?

Comment: syntax error /typo => `_construct` - 3rd one I see within an hour. Are you all taking the same code from the same place?! *sigh*

Comment: @Bhandhavya Reddy Make your title of your question shorter

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is `__construct` with 2x underscores, not 1x `_construct`

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Make that change for all instances of it and use error reporting:

- https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

change your controller index function like following

```
function index()
{
   $data['result']=$this->m->gettable();
   $this->load->view("index",$data);
}
```

On view page change it as following.

```
  foreach($result as $row)

 {

  echo "<tr>
  <td>$row->id</td>
  <td>$row->studentname</td>
  <td>$row->gender</td>
   <td>$row->phone</td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>";

      }
```

this will  work.